# Check if java Timestamp is null in jpql query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have the following code:

```
    @Query("select t from Training t join t.skills s join t.trainers tr join t.discipline d  where " +
            "(t.name in :names or :names is null) and (s.name in :skills or :skills is null) and" +
            " (t.location = :location or :location is null) and " +
            " (d.name = :discipline or :discipline is null) and " +
            "(tr.firstName in :trainers or :trainers is null) and " +
            " (((:endDate > t.endDate) and (:startDate < t.startDate)) or (:startDate is empty))")
    public List<Training> filterTrainings(List<String> names, List<String> skills, String location,String discipline,List<String> trainers,Timestamp endDate,Timestamp startDate);
```

and i need to check if `:startDate` and `:endDate` are null. Is there a way to do that?

The error i get is `nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

when trying to check `:startDate is null` where start date is a Timestamp.

Comment: Do you have to check before or after the join if the dates are null?

Comment: I don't think it matters for me..

Comment: How is this different than [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687450/)?

Comment: Then what is your problem with `:endDate IS NULL` respectively `endDate IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: i get an error like "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Comment: anyone up for some help? i really don't know how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try passing a LocalDateTime as a parameter instead of a Timestamp? java.sql.Timestamp might be causing you issues here. You can convert to a LocalDateTime by calling timestamp.toLocalDateTime()

Alternatively you could try passing the timestamp as a string into filterTrainings. If the timestamp is null before calling the filterTrainings method, assign an empty string. `String _timestamp = timestamp == null ? "" : timestamp.toString()`

Then, in your sql statement check if the string is empty .. `""=:timestamp OR function("to_timestamp", :timestamp, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff")`. The problem here is that we are using *function* to access native db commands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build your SQL query with a `and COALESCE(field, default_value_for_datetime_field)`. So you will not get NULL values.

You can build a default value as the start of the current month, of the current week, or any datetime value which could be a fair substitution for your model domain.